# Inputting values into .css()

Tags: javascript

I am trying to substitute values into `w` and `h` but it does not seem to take it at all.  got a solution?

```
var width = img.Width;
var height = img.Height;

var w = window.innerWidth+"px";
var h = window.innerHeight+"px";      

$('#outer').css('background-size','w h');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting the background size to a string "`w h`" instead of the variables.

```
$('#outer').css('background-size',w+" "+h);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
            $('#outer').css('background-size',w+' '+h);
```